# Connection to re-directed URL failed! Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, arduino-esp32

Good afternoon everyone, I've been working on a project that uploads data to a google sheets sheet but at the time of testing the code it only publishes the data two or three times in the sheet, after this the connection is lost, I already tried several ways to solve it but I can't (It's my first time experiencing WiFi with Google Sheets), I would greatly appreciate some guidance on this topic.
These are some variables that I am using for the reconnection.

```
int error_count=0;
int connect_count=0;
const unsigned int MAX_CONNECT=20;
bool flag=false;
```

In the setup function I tried this configuration that tells me that the host connects well.

```
WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
while(WiFi.status()!=WL_CONNECTED){
  Serial.print(".");
  delay(500);
}
Serial.println();
Serial.println("Conexión Wi-Fi establecida");
client = new HTTPSRedirect(httpsPort);
client->setInsecure();
client->setPrintResponseBody(true);
client->setContentTypeHeader("application/json");
delay(5000);
Serial.print("Connecting to ");
Serial.println(host);
bool flag = false;
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){ 
  int retval=client->connect(host, httpsPort);
  if (retval==1){
    flag = true;
    String msg = "Connected. OK";
    Serial.println(msg);
    delay(2000);
    break;
  }
  else
    Serial.println("Connection failed. Retrying...");
}
if (!flag){
  Serial.print("Could not connect to server: ");
  Serial.println(host);
  delay(5000);
  return;
}
delete client;
client=nullptr;
```

In the loop function use this setting to reconnect the host.

```
if(!flag){
  client=new HTTPSRedirect(httpsPort);
  client->setInsecure();
  flag=true;
  client->setPrintResponseBody(true);
  client->setContentTypeHeader("application/json"); 
}
if(client!=nullptr){
  if(!client->connected()){
    int retval=client->connect(host, httpsPort);
    if(retval!=1){
      Serial.println("Disconnected. Retrying...");
      flag=false;
      return;
    }
  }
}
else{
  Serial.println("¡Error al crear el objeto del cliente!");
  error_count=5;
}
if(connect_count>MAX_CONNECT){
  connect_count=0;
  flag=false;
  delete client;
  return;
}
/*if(client->GET(url1, host)){
  payload1 = client->getResponseBody();
  payload1.trim();
  ++connect_count;
}
if(client->GET(url2, host)){
  payload2=client->getResponseBody();
  payload2.trim();
  ++connect_count;
}*/
if (error_count>3){
  Serial.println("Procesador detenido...");
  delete client;
  client=nullptr;
}
delay(1000);
//int Fecha1=payload1.toInt();
//int Fecha2=payload2.toInt();
//Serial.println(Fecha1);
//Serial.println(Fecha2);
SendData(Upload_Data);
```

The SendData function is responsible for sending the data.

```
void SendData(String value){
  String Implementation_ID="AKfycbySelLW32HKb-xTacKpxFi9nP-9iKtQKnnumD5mJVVzR7CmNfuDq9vwiBAO5mw31FVrMQ";
  String URL=String("/macros/s/")+Implementation_ID+"/exec";
  payload=payload_base+"\""+1.00+","+1+","+1+"\"}";
  Serial.println("Subiendo datos...");
  Serial.println(payload);
  if(client->POST(URL, host, payload)){
    client->stop();
  }
  delay(5000);
}
```

But as I mentioned before once I try the code it works two or three times and I get the following error.

```
Connection to re-directed URL failed!
Disconnected. Retrying...
```

I tried many ways to solve this error but I can't get it fixed, I just hope I can solve the reconnection, I would be very grateful for any help you can give me.

Updating of information:
@hcheung Thank you very much for your help, what I understood at the moment of implementing the example code to my code is that a redirection is made since it is connecting to the host of script.google.com in an insecure way this worked for me and it only uploads the data two or three times and it disconnects then I will attach all my code with the libraries that I am using.

```
//Librerias
///AKfycbySelLW32HKb-xTacKpxFi9nP- 
9iKtQKnnumD5mJVVzR7CmNfuDq9vwiBAO5mw31FVrMQ->Datos recibidos en Sheets
///AKfycbyJDxdFaR4FuMMD2fOfhXZWdX2ZlIBfjteY4pwePI1NuQVi4eE-uM0-lWppz-EH1sM->Datos enviados de la prueba
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <MD_MAX72xx.h>
#include "FS.h"
#include "SD.h"
#include "SPI.h"
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include <esp_crt_bundle.h>
#include <ssl_client.h>
#include <DebugMacros.h>
#include <HTTPSRedirect.h>
//Defines tiempos
#define  DELAYTIME  100 //in milliseconds
#define  DELAYTIME2 500
//Defines pines
#define MAX_DEVICES  4
#define CHAR_SPACING 1
#define CLK_PIN      18 //or SCK
#define DATA_PIN     23 //or MOSI
#define CS_PIN       5 //or SS
#define SCK          14
#define MISO         27
#define MOSI         13
#define CS           15
//Defines variables
#define HARDWARE_TYPE MD_MAX72XX::FC16_HW
//Variables utilizando las librerias
SPIClass spi0=SPIClass(HSPI);
MD_MAX72XX mx=MD_MAX72XX(HARDWARE_TYPE, DATA_PIN, CLK_PIN, CS_PIN, MAX_DEVICES);
HTTPSRedirect* client=nullptr;
//Variables
int error_count=0;
int connect_count=0;
const unsigned int MAX_CONNECT=20;
const int httpsPort=443;
const char *ssid="FAMILIA FARFAN";
const char *password="Jejmpn199020";
const char *host="script.google.com";
const char *GScriptId="AKfycbyJDxdFaR4FuMMD2fOfhXZWdX2ZlIBfjteY4pwePI1NuQVi4eE-uM0-lWppz-EH1sM"; //Recibiendo datos desde google sheets (dirección de script)
const char *cellAddress1="A1";
const char *cellAddress2="A2";
String payload_base = "{\"command\": \"insert_row\", \"sheet_name\":\"HojadeDatos\", \"values\": ";
String url1=String("/macros/s/") + GScriptId + "/exec?read=" + cellAddress1;
String url2=String("/macros/s/") + GScriptId + "/exec?read=" + cellAddress2;
String payload="";
String payload1="";
String payload2="";
String Upload_Data="";
bool flag=false;
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  spi0.begin(SCK, MISO, MOSI, CS);
  mx.begin();
  Serial.print("Conectando a la red Wi-Fi");
  while(WiFi.status()!=WL_CONNECTED){
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Conexión Wi-Fi establecida");
  if(!SD.begin(CS, spi0)){
    Serial.println("Card Mount Failed");
    return;
  }
  client = new HTTPSRedirect(httpsPort);
  client->setInsecure();
  client->setPrintResponseBody(true);
  client->setContentTypeHeader("application/json");
  delay(5000);
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(host);
  bool flag = false;
  for(int i=0; i<5; i++){ 
    int retval=client->connect(host, httpsPort);
    if (retval==1){
      flag = true;
      String msg = "Connected. OK";
      Serial.println(msg);
      delay(2000);
      break;
    }
    else
      Serial.println("Connection failed. Retrying...");
  }
  if (!flag){
    Serial.print("Could not connect to server: ");
    Serial.println(host);
    delay(5000);
    return;
  }
  delete client;
  client=nullptr;
  uint64_t cardSize=SD.cardSize()/(1024*1024);
  Serial.printf("SD Card Size: %lluMB\n", cardSize);
  Serial.printf("Total space: %lluMB\n", SD.totalBytes()/(1024 * 1024));
  Serial.printf("Used space: %lluMB\n", SD.usedBytes()/(1024 * 1024));
}

void loop(){
  while(true){
    char buff[9]={72, 111, 108, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97};
    int val1=1;
    int val2=1;
    int val3=1;
    if(!SD.exists("/hello.csv")){
      createFile(SD, "/hello.csv");
    }
    scrollText(buff);
    appendFile(SD, "/hello.csv", val1, val2, val3);
    readFile(SD, "/hello.csv");
    if(!flag){
      client=new HTTPSRedirect(httpsPort);
      client->setInsecure();
      flag=true;
      client->setPrintResponseBody(true);
      client->setContentTypeHeader("application/json"); 
    }
    if(client!=nullptr){
      if(!client->connected()){
        int retval=client->connect(host, httpsPort);
        if(retval!=1){
          Serial.println("Disconnected. Retrying...");
          flag=false;
          return;
        }
      }
    }
    else{
      Serial.println("¡Error al crear el objeto del cliente!");
      error_count=5;
    }
    if(connect_count>MAX_CONNECT){
      connect_count=0;
      flag=false;
      delete client;
      return;
    }
    /*if(client->GET(url1, host)){
      payload1 = client->getResponseBody();
      payload1.trim();
      ++connect_count;
    }
    if(client->GET(url2, host)){
      payload2=client->getResponseBody();
      payload2.trim();
      ++connect_count;
    }*/
    if (error_count>3){
      Serial.println("Procesador detenido...");
      delete client;
      client=nullptr;
    }
    delay(1000);
    //int Fecha1=payload1.toInt();
    //int Fecha2=payload2.toInt();
    //Serial.println(Fecha1);
    //Serial.println(Fecha2);
    SendData(Upload_Data);
  }
}
void scrollText(char *p){
  uint8_t charWidth;
  uint8_t cBuf[8];
  mx.clear();
  while(*p!='\0'){
    charWidth = mx.getChar(*p++, sizeof(cBuf)/sizeof(cBuf[0]), cBuf);
    for(uint8_t i=0; i<=(charWidth); i++){
      mx.transform(MD_MAX72XX::TSL);
      if (i<charWidth)
        mx.setColumn(0, cBuf[i]);
      delay(DELAYTIME);
    }
  }
  delay(DELAYTIME);
}
void createFile(fs::FS &fs, const char * path){
  Serial.printf("Creando archivo: %s\n", path);
  File file = fs.open(path, FILE_WRITE);
  if(file){
    file.close();
  }
  else{
    Serial.println("Error archivo");
  }
}
void readFile(fs::FS &fs, const char * path){
  Serial.printf("Leyendo archivo: %s\n", path);
  File file = fs.open(path);
  if(!file){
    Serial.println("Error al abrir el archivo para leer.");
    return;
  }
  while(file.available()){
    Upload_Data=Upload_Data+file.readString();
  }
  file.close();
}
void deleteFile(fs::FS &fs, const char * path){
  Serial.printf("Eliminando archivo: %s\n", path);
  if(fs.remove(path)){
    Serial.println("Archivo eliminado.");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Error al eliminar el archivo.");
  }
}
void appendFile(fs::FS &fs, const char * path, int message, int message1, int message2){
  File file = fs.open(path, FILE_APPEND);
  if(file){
    file.print(message);
    file.print(",");
    file.print(message1);
    file.print(",");
    file.println(message2);
    file.close();
  }
  else{
   Serial.println("Error al abrir archivo.");
  }
}
void SendData(String value){
  String Implementation_ID="AKfycbySelLW32HKb-xTacKpxFi9nP-9iKtQKnnumD5mJVVzR7CmNfuDq9vwiBAO5mw31FVrMQ";
  String URL=String("/macros/s/")+Implementation_ID+"/exec";
  payload=payload_base+"\""+1.00+","+1+","+1+"\"}";
  Serial.println("Subiendo datos...");
  Serial.println(payload);
  if(client->POST(URL, host, payload)){
    client->stop();
  }
  delay(5000);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your post to show your complete sketch than some snippets of your code. Why do you need to manually handle the redirect is puzzled to me, what kind of issues you are facing that force you to do that? Typically redirect occured when you are trying to connect to the site with non-secure HTTP and the site will force to a secure HTTPS with a re-direct, if you are connecting with the server with correct HTTPS, there will be no redirect.

Comment: Please take a look at [BasicHttpsClient](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/HTTPClient/examples/BasicHttpsClient/BasicHttpsClient.ino) example that come with your ESP32 installation.

Comment: @hcheung Thank you very much for your help, what I understood at the moment of implementing the example code to my code is that a redirection is made since it is connecting to the host of script.google.com in an insecure way this worked for me and it only uploads the data two or three times and it disconnects then I will attach all my code with the libraries that I am using.

Comment: @hcheung One last question, with the example that you shared with me I was reading it to understand it and I almost managed to finish understanding it. My only question is if with this method I will also be able to read the data from my ESP32 from a Google Sheets, since I also require that a Google Sheets share data to my ESP32.
Thank you very much for your answers, and indications for this forum.